# How to animate some part of an SVG

Tags: css, css-animations, svg-animate

I have an SVG which looks something like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

</head>
<body>

<svg version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
 width="512.000000pt" height="512.000000pt" viewBox="0 0 512.000000 512.000000"
 preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">

<g transform="translate(0.000000,512.000000) scale(0.100000,-0.100000)"
fill="#000000" stroke="none">
<path d="M405 5109 c-194 -28 -367 -205 -395 -404 -13 -92 -13 -1000 0 -1090
12 -78 47 -162 91 -217 l29 -37 -33 -44 c-45 -59 -75 -133 -87 -214 -13 -89
-13 -997 0 -1086 12 -81 42 -155 87 -214 l33 -43 -33 -43 c-45 -59 -75 -133
-87 -214 -13 -88 -13 -997 0 -1088 29 -204 201 -376 405 -405 42 -6 427 -10
948 -10 l877 0 0 160 0 160 -907 0 c-888 0 -909 1 -941 20 -18 11 -41 34 -52
52 -19 32 -20 52 -20 568 0 516 1 536 20 568 11 18 34 41 52 52 32 19 53 20
941 20 l907 0 0 160 0 160 -907 0 c-888 0 -909 1 -941 20 -18 11 -41 34 -52
52 -19 32 -20 52 -20 568 0 516 1 536 20 568 11 18 34 41 52 52 33 20 55 20
1848 20 1793 0 1815 0 1848 -20 59 -36 72 -71 72 -192 l0 -108 160 0 160 0 0
78 c-1 163 -33 279 -101 364 l-29 37 33 44 c45 59 75 133 87 214 13 88 13 997
0 1088 -29 204 -201 376 -405 405 -88 12 -3574 11 -3660 -1z m3683 -329 c18
-11 41 -34 52 -52 19 -32 20 -52 20 -568 0 -516 -1 -536 -20 -568 -11 -18 -34
-41 -52 -52 -33 -20 -55 -20 -1848 -20 -1793 0 -1815 0 -1848 20 -18 11 -41
34 -52 52 -19 32 -20 52 -20 568 0 516 1 536 20 568 11 18 34 41 52 52 33 20
55 20 1848 20 1793 0 1815 0 1848 -20z"/>
<path d="M760 4308 c-112 -31 -149 -170 -68 -255 105 -110 296 -3 256 145 -12
44 -60 98 -97 107 -14 3 -33 8 -41 9 -8 2 -31 0 -50 -6z"/>
<path d="M760 2708 c-112 -31 -149 -170 -68 -255 105 -110 296 -3 256 145 -12
44 -60 98 -97 107 -14 3 -33 8 -41 9 -8 2 -31 0 -50 -6z"/>

<g class="loading">
<path d="M3728 2550 c-549 -49 -1007 -450 -1133 -992 -24 -103 -34 -266 -24
-385 20 -258 119 -499 287 -705 l75 -90 110 110 110 110 -51 61 c-102 123
-176 276 -208 430 -22 114 -15 343 15 446 94 327 348 583 672 675 115 33 449
41 449 10 0 -4 -34 -52 -76 -105 -70 -90 -74 -98 -57 -110 10 -7 65 -49 123
-94 58 -44 108 -77 112 -73 4 4 96 124 206 267 l199 259 -106 48 c-254 116
-469 158 -703 138z"/>
<path d="M4636 2071 l-109 -109 52 -62 c102 -123 175 -275 206 -428 23 -114
17 -334 -13 -445 -41 -151 -153 -339 -263 -443 -111 -105 -275 -198 -416 -236
-118 -31 -443 -38 -443 -9 0 4 34 51 75 104 l75 97 -48 37 c-94 74 -192 148
-197 148 -3 0 -97 -119 -209 -265 l-203 -265 120 -53 c233 -103 363 -133 577
-133 149 0 262 16 385 56 452 148 788 531 871 995 20 113 20 330 -1 445 -35
194 -117 381 -241 545 -113 150 -92 148 -218 21z"/>
</g>

<path d="M760 1108 c-112 -31 -149 -170 -68 -255 105 -110 296 -3 256 145 -12
44 -60 98 -97 107 -14 3 -33 8 -41 9 -8 2 -31 0 -50 -6z"/>
</g>
</svg>




</body>
</html>
```

I'm sorry for the previous post not being clear.
the arrows are at the bottom of the icon. When I tried to rotate the arrows it rotates erratically and goes all over the screen.

Can anybody help me with css animation?. I want to show these arrows as continuously rotating arrows.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Enclose the paths you want to apply the CSS animation to in `<g>` tag.
2. Find the axis on which the component must rotate.
   In the above case paths are enclosed inside a square so center is at 50% from top and 50% from left. use `transform-origin: 50% 50%` to set point about which the component has to rotate.

```css
.running {
        transform-box: fill-box;
        transform-origin: 50% 50%;
        animation: spin 3s linear infinite;
        }

        @keyframes spin {
        0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
        100% { transform: rotate(-360deg); }
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
<svg version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
 width="512.000000pt" height="512.000000pt" viewBox="0 0 512.000000 512.000000"
 preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
<g transform="translate(0.000000,512.000000) scale(0.100000,-0.100000)"
fill="#000000" stroke="none">
<path d="M405 5109 c-194 -28 -367 -205 -395 -404 -13 -92 -13 -1000 0 -1090
12 -78 47 -162 91 -217 l29 -37 -33 -44 c-45 -59 -75 -133 -87 -214 -13 -89
-13 -997 0 -1086 12 -81 42 -155 87 -214 l33 -43 -33 -43 c-45 -59 -75 -133
-87 -214 -13 -88 -13 -997 0 -1088 29 -204 201 -376 405 -405 42 -6 427 -10
948 -10 l877 0 0 160 0 160 -907 0 c-888 0 -909 1 -941 20 -18 11 -41 34 -52
52 -19 32 -20 52 -20 568 0 516 1 536 20 568 11 18 34 41 52 52 32 19 53 20
941 20 l907 0 0 160 0 160 -907 0 c-888 0 -909 1 -941 20 -18 11 -41 34 -52
52 -19 32 -20 52 -20 568 0 516 1 536 20 568 11 18 34 41 52 52 33 20 55 20
1848 20 1793 0 1815 0 1848 -20 59 -36 72 -71 72 -192 l0 -108 160 0 160 0 0
78 c-1 163 -33 279 -101 364 l-29 37 33 44 c45 59 75 133 87 214 13 88 13 997
0 1088 -29 204 -201 376 -405 405 -88 12 -3574 11 -3660 -1z m3683 -329 c18
-11 41 -34 52 -52 19 -32 20 -52 20 -568 0 -516 -1 -536 -20 -568 -11 -18 -34
-41 -52 -52 -33 -20 -55 -20 -1848 -20 -1793 0 -1815 0 -1848 20 -18 11 -41
34 -52 52 -19 32 -20 52 -20 568 0 516 1 536 20 568 11 18 34 41 52 52 33 20
55 20 1848 20 1793 0 1815 0 1848 -20z"/>
<path d="M760 4308 c-112 -31 -149 -170 -68 -255 105 -110 296 -3 256 145 -12
44 -60 98 -97 107 -14 3 -33 8 -41 9 -8 2 -31 0 -50 -6z"/>
<path d="M760 2708 c-112 -31 -149 -170 -68 -255 105 -110 296 -3 256 145 -12
44 -60 98 -97 107 -14 3 -33 8 -41 9 -8 2 -31 0 -50 -6z"/>
    <g class="running">
        <path d="M3728 2550 c-549 -49 -1007 -450 -1133 -992 -24 -103 -34 -266 -24
        -385 20 -258 119 -499 287 -705 l75 -90 110 110 110 110 -51 61 c-102 123
        -176 276 -208 430 -22 114 -15 343 15 446 94 327 348 583 672 675 115 33 449
        41 449 10 0 -4 -34 -52 -76 -105 -70 -90 -74 -98 -57 -110 10 -7 65 -49 123
        -94 58 -44 108 -77 112 -73 4 4 96 124 206 267 l199 259 -106 48 c-254 116
        -469 158 -703 138z"/>
        <path d="M4636 2071 l-109 -109 52 -62 c102 -123 175 -275 206 -428 23 -114
        17 -334 -13 -445 -41 -151 -153 -339 -263 -443 -111 -105 -275 -198 -416 -236
        -118 -31 -443 -38 -443 -9 0 4 34 51 75 104 l75 97 -48 37 c-94 74 -192 148
        -197 148 -3 0 -97 -119 -209 -265 l-203 -265 120 -53 c233 -103 363 -133 577
        -133 149 0 262 16 385 56 452 148 788 531 871 995 20 113 20 330 -1 445 -35
        194 -117 381 -241 545 -113 150 -92 148 -218 21z"/>
    </g>
<path d="M760 1108 c-112 -31 -149 -170 -68 -255 105 -110 296 -3 256 145 -12
44 -60 98 -97 107 -14 3 -33 8 -41 9 -8 2 -31 0 -50 -6z"/>
</svg>
</body>
</html>
```

Note: transform box doesn't work on Edge or IE see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-box for more information.

Comment: Dear @shubhambhuyan, Do I understand clearly? Do you mean the answer should not edit the SVG you posted in the current question?

Comment: yea, It shouldn't change the SVG.
I infact changed the SVG and uploaded the original one now. So this new one should help.

Comment: Dear @shubhambhuyan, I see the new SVG, do you want just the Circle to rotate?

Comment: Yes, I just want the circle to rotate.
I have tried several ways, it rotates over the whole icon/screen.

Comment: @shubhambhuyan, I saw something like you want before. the technic of CSS that name was SMIL. but for this requirement, you have two critical issues. _1_: you should select `path` number 4 and 5 (the circle) for injecting style by using CSS _2_: rotate each part (I mean each part of the circle) around the center of the circle. Both of them are so hard but it is not impossible. please give me time. I will fix it for you about 3 hours later.

Comment: Yea, I tried to find how to rotate specific paths about it's center. Couldn't find anything that works. Thanks @AmerllicA for investing your time in this and helping me out.

Comment: Dear @shubhambhuyan, for rotating a part you can use `transform: rotate(169deg); transform-box: fill-box; transform-origin: 69px 85px;`. ( the numbers are sample). but the number should fix exactly. but I worry about selecting. I will make the CSS but selecting the `path` number 4 and number 5 is so hard by my sight.

Comment: for that we can do something like this,
`<g class="loading">
<path d="...."/>

<path d="....."/>
</g>`

We can apply CSS class to this

Comment: It works!!!!!
`.loading {

transform-box: fill-box;
transform-origin: 50% 50%;
animation: rotate 1.5s infinite linear;
}


@keyframes rotate {
   0% {
      transform: rotate(0deg);
   }
   100% {
      transform: rotate(360deg);
   }
}`

`<g class="loading">
<path d="...."/>

<path d="...."/>
</g>`

This serves the purpose, Thanks @AmerllicA, wouldn't be possible without your help.

Comment: Dear Bro @shubhambhuyan, thanks for your attention and all of my answers are duty and you're welcome, sorry for my late comment answer. My wife wants my time for a little talk , Because you are a newbie on Stack Overflow, I recommend you edit my answer and then mark it as the correct answer. Let the other developers search and find the right way in the future. (**My Request**: _Please do **not** upvote me, just mark the correct answer_)

Comment: I have edited the answer. Thanks for guiding me, and a big thanks for finding a solution.

Comment: Nice to see this working solution! Didn't know this was possible at all. So also a big thanks and an upvote! I've tested this in several browsers and this works for me on Chrome/Safari and FF. Only in Edge 18 it still rotates over the wrong axis. As for IE11 it doesn't move. Perhaps any idea if this could possibly be fixed in them (or at least in Edge)?

Comment: @Nick Van Loocke, Thanks for review. I had tried work around to get this working.
we have to use `-webkit- , -moz- , -ms-`. Unfortunately IE and edge do not support `transformation-box` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-box), Without this it may not be possible cuz it'll take the whole box enclosing the icon, instead of the square box which encloses the circle.

Answer (score 3):

You could work with this rotating animation:

```
svg {
  animation: rotate 1s infinite linear;
}


@keyframes rotate {
   from {transform:rotate(0deg);}
   to {transform:rotate(359deg);}
}
```

For more information see perhaps https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/keyframe-animation-syntax/

Answer (score 2):

You can resolve your issue with below snippet.

```html
<html>

<head>
    <title></title>
    <style>
        .image {
            -webkit-animation: spin 4s linear infinite;
            -moz-animation: spin 4s linear infinite;
            animation: spin 4s linear infinite;
        }

        @-moz-keyframes spin {
            100% {
                -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
            }
        }

        @-webkit-keyframes spin {
            100% {
                -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
            }
        }

        @keyframes spin {
            100% {
                -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
                transform: rotate(360deg);
            }
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
        x="0px" y="0px" width="255.373px" height="255.51px" class="image" viewBox="0 0 255.373 255.51"
        enable-background="new 0 0 255.373 255.51" xml:space="preserve">
        <g transform="translate(0.000000,512.000000) scale(0.100000,-0.100000)">
            <path d="M1170.85,5105.209c-548.994-49.004-1007.002-450-1132.998-992.002c-24.004-102.998-33.999-265.996-24.004-385
  c20-257.998,119.004-498.994,287.002-705l75-90l110,110l110,110l-50.996,61.006c-102.002,122.998-176.006,275.996-207.998,430
  c-22.002,113.994-15,342.998,15,445.996c93.994,327.002,347.998,582.998,671.992,675c115,32.998,449.004,40.996,449.004,10
  c0-4.004-34.004-52.002-75.996-105c-70-90-74.004-97.998-57.002-110c10-7.002,65-49.004,122.998-94.004
  c57.998-43.994,107.998-76.992,112.002-72.998c3.994,4.004,95.996,124.004,205.996,267.002l199.004,259.004l-106.006,47.998
  C1619.853,5083.208,1404.854,5125.209,1170.85,5105.209z" />
            <path d="M2078.847,4626.206l-108.994-108.994l52.002-62.002c101.992-122.998,175-275,205.996-427.998
  c22.998-114.004,17.002-334.004-12.998-445c-41.006-151.006-152.998-339.004-262.998-442.998
  c-111.006-105-275-198.008-416.006-236.006c-117.998-30.996-442.998-37.998-442.998-8.994c0,3.994,34.004,50.996,75,103.994
  l75,97.002l-47.998,37.002c-94.004,73.994-192.002,147.998-197.002,147.998c-2.998,0-97.002-119.004-209.004-265l-202.998-265
  l120-52.998c232.998-102.998,362.998-133.003,577.002-133.003c149.004,0,262.002,16.001,385,56.001
  c452.002,147.998,787.998,530.996,870.996,995c20,112.998,20,330-0.996,445c-35,194.004-117.002,380.996-240.996,545
  C2183.847,4755.209,2204.853,4753.208,2078.847,4626.206z" />
        </g>
    </svg>

</body>

</html>
```